# Find the longest substring in a string

Tags: ruby

I would like to find the longest sequence of repeated characters in a string.

ex:

```
"aabbccc" #=> ccc
"aabbbddccdddd" #=> dddd
```

etc

In the first example, ccc is the longest sequence because c is repeated 3 times. In the second example, dddd is the longest sequence because d is repeated 4 times.

It should be something like this:

```
b = []
a.scan(/(.)(.)(.)/) do |x,y,z|
    b<<x<<y<<z if x==y && y==z
end
```

but with some flags to keep the count of repeating, I guess

Comment: it just adds the letters to the arr

Comment: It's a very odd thing you've got going on there.

Comment: Not clear what you mean. The longest substring of a string is itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
string = 'aabbccc'
string.chars.chunk {|a| a}.max_by {|_, ary| ary.length}.last.join
```

### Update:

Explanation of `|_, ary|`: at this point we have array of 2-element arrays. We only need to use the second one and we ignore the first one. If instead we do `|char, ary|` some IDEs would complain about unused local variable. Placing `_` tells ruby to ignore that value.

### Using regex:

We can achieve same thing with regex:

```
string.scan(/([a-z])(\1*)/).map(&:join).max_by(&:length)
```

Comment: Can u explain this {|_, ary| plz

Comment: I was going to try `slice_before` but this is even better.

Comment: That's a fun one to run through irb and build the statement operation by operation to see what chunk, max, last, join all do. Well done.

Comment: @UriAgassi - Yes, but scan unfortunately returns array of matched groups if there are any, not the whole matched text. Hence the need to group the backreference as well and then join them to get the whole text.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using a regular expression:

```
LETTER_MATCH = Regexp.new(('a'..'z').collect do |letter|
  "#{letter}+"
end.join('|'))

def repeated(string)
  string.scan(LETTER_MATCH).sort_by(&:length).last
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution. It's bigger but it still works)

```
def most_friquent_char_in_a_row(my_str)
  my_str = my_str.chars
  temp=[]
  ary=[]

  for i in 0..my_str.count-1
    if my_str[i]==my_str[i+1]
      temp<<my_str[i] unless temp.include?(my_str[i])
      temp<<my_str[i+1]   
    else 
      ary<<temp
      temp=[]
    end
  end
  result = ary.max_by(&:size).join
  p "#{result} - #{result.size}" 
end
```