# Elixir find the longest substring in a string

Tags: elixir

My question is exactly the same as [Find the longest substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191185/find-the-longest-substring-in-a-string)

But related to elixir

My current implementation is very ugly:

```
str = "aabbbssssssggssrrrr"
String.split(str, "") |> Enum.chunk_while([], fn elem, acc ->
  cond do
    (length(acc) == 0) -> 
    {:cont, [elem]}
    (acc == [""]) -> 
      {:cont, [elem]}
    (List.last(acc) == elem) -> 
      {:cont, [elem | acc]}
    true -> 
    {:cont, Enum.reverse(acc), []}
  end
end,
fn
  [] -> {:cont, []}
  acc -> {:cont, Enum.reverse(acc), []}
end) |> Enum.map(fn e -> Enum.reduce(e, "", &<>/2) end) |> Enum.max_by(&String.length/1)
```

Is it possible to write one-liner like in ruby or at least something shorter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) solution with chunks is extremely poor. It performs several absolutely unneeded operations, like splitting, joining etc, which might drastically decrease the performance on long inputs.

The simplest way would be to use regular expression with a [back reference](https://regular-expressions.mobi/refcapture.html?wlr=1).

```rb
str = "aabbbssssssggssrrrr"
Regex.scan(~r/(.)\1{1,}/, str, capture: :first)
#⇒ [["aa"], ["bbb"], ["ssssss"], ["gg"], ["ss"], ["rrrr"]]
```

Now it’s a matter of preference how to get to the longest string, for instance:

```rb
~r/(.)\1{1,}/
|> Regex.scan(str, capture: :first)
|> Enum.sort_by(&-String.length(hd(&1)))
|> hd()
|> hd()
#⇒ "ssssss"
```

or, with `List.flatten/1`

```rb
~r/(.)\1{1,}/
|> Regex.scan(str, capture: :first)
|> List.flatten()
|> Enum.sort_by(&-String.length(&1))
|> hd()
#⇒ "ssssss"
```

Answer (score 3):

The most *elixirish* solution would be to use [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html?#reduce/3) which makes this `O(N)` with a single input pass.

```rb
"aabbbssssssggssrrrr"
|> to_charlist()
|> Enum.reduce(%{char: ??, curr: 0, max: []}, fn
  ch, %{char: ch, max: max, curr: curr} when curr < length(max) -> 
    %{char: ch, max: max, curr: curr + 1}

  ch, %{char: ch, curr: curr} -> 
    %{char: ch, max: List.duplicate([ch], curr + 1), curr: curr + 1}

  ch, %{max: max} ->
    %{char: ch, max: max, curr: 1}
end)
|> Map.get(:max)
|> Enum.join()
#⇒ "ssssss"
```

Comment: this should perform better than regex, since regex cannot be optimized by compiler.

Comment: @Daniel yes, that is why I have it posted; still, unless we are certain we are to lookup through gigabytes, regex in more readable IMSO.